# Receive on usb bluetooth and send it to uart

Tags: usb, bluetooth, uart

Is there any easy way to receive data on cheap USB Bluetooth dongle and all of data send to the UART in Raspberry?

Comment: Welcome to SE :) Plase have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/180072

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to receive over Bluetooth into USB, then re-transmit through the UART?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) for attaching sockets to sockets, including network, tty, files, proxies etc. It might be as easy as:

```
$ socat /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyS0
```

(You need the right devices, of course.)